# How to gradually update images in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a web page which is table with 2 cells on one row.

The cells should display an image which gradually fades into another image (one of three for each cell).

While this works for one cell, with both cells the images are displayed on top of each other.

This is from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-transition-with-fading-effect-using-javascript/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> b
 
<style> 
    body { 
        text-align: center; 
    }   
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table {border-collapse: separate;  border-spacing: 10px 20px;}

table, 
table td;}
</style>  
</head>   
<body> 
 <table class="center" style="max-width:100%"> 
    <tr><td>
        <div id="1"> 
            <img src= "image1.jpg" 
                 class="test2" /> 
           <img src="image2.jpg"  
                 class="test2" /> 
            <img src="image3.jpg" 
                 class="test2" /> 
        </div> 
      </td></tr>
      <tr><td>
      <div id="2">
      <img src= "image4.jpg"
         class="test" /> 
       <img src="image5.jpg" 
         class="test" />  
      <img src="image6.jpg"
         class="test" />  
    </div>
  </td></tr></table>
<script> 
    startImageTransition1(); 
    startImageTransition2(); 
    function startImageTransition1() { 
        var images = document.getElementsByClassName("test"); 

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) { 
            images[i].style.opacity = 1; 
        } 

        var top = 1; 

        var cur = images.length - 1; 

        setInterval(changeImage, 3000); 

        async function changeImage() { 

            var nextImage = (1 + cur) % images.length; 

            images[cur].style.zIndex = top + 1; 
            images[nextImage].style.zIndex = top; 

            await transition(); 

            images[cur].style.zIndex = top; 

            images[nextImage].style.zIndex = top + 1; 

            top = top + 1; 

            images[cur].style.opacity = 1; 
            
            cur = nextImage; 

        } 

        function transition() { 
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
                var del = 0.01; 

                var id = setInterval(changeOpacity, 10); 

                function changeOpacity() { 
                    images[cur].style.opacity -= del; 
                    if (images[cur].style.opacity <= 0) { 
                        clearInterval(id); 
                        resolve(); 
                    } 
                } 

            }) 
        } 
    } 
    
     function startImageTransition2() { 
        var images = document.getElementsByClassName("test2"); 

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) { 
            images[i].style.opacity = 1; 
        } 

        var top = 1; 

        var cur = images.length - 1; 

        setInterval(changeImage, 3000); 

        async function changeImage() { 

            var nextImage = (1 + cur) % images.length; 

            images[cur].style.zIndex = top + 1; 
            images[nextImage].style.zIndex = top; 

            await transition(); 

            images[cur].style.zIndex = top; 

            images[nextImage].style.zIndex = top + 1; 

            top = top + 1; 

            images[cur].style.opacity = 1; 
            
            cur = nextImage; 

        } 

        function transition() { 
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
                var del = 0.01; 

                var id = setInterval(changeOpacity, 10); 

                function changeOpacity() { 
                    images[cur].style.opacity -= del; 
                    if (images[cur].style.opacity <= 0) { 
                        clearInterval(id); 
                        resolve(); 
                    } 
                } 

            }) 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML, CSS, and Javascript here? http://jsfiddle.net/Sapphion/nU477/ or here? http://jsfiddle.net/crazyrohila/tczsC/ or here? https://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/GMfSB/  Is any of that code usable?

Comment: I will tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using CSS animations instead of a JS/setInterval solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether a CSS animation solution would be viable in the actual use case behind the question, but given the info in the question, which includes the fact that there are the same number of images in each cell, here is a non-Javascript method using CSS animations.

```css
@keyframes rotateimgs {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
}

td {
  position: relative;
  --interval: 5s;/* set this to what you want the fade-in time to be */
}

img.fadeinout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: rotateimgs;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--interval) * 3);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

img.fadeinout:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  position: relative;/* if your images are of different sizes, put this on the tallest */
}
img.fadeinout:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: var(--interval);
  }
img.fadeinout:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--interval) * 2);
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <img class="fadeinout" src= "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142245/CSS8.png" /> 
        <img class="fadeinout" src= "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142309/php7.png" /> 
        <img class="fadeinout" src= "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142254/html9.png" /> 
    </td>
    <td>class="fadeinout" 
        <img class="fadeinout" src= "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142254/html9.png" /> 
        <img class="fadeinout" src= "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142245/CSS8.png" /> 
        <img class="fadeinout" src= "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20200318142309/php7.png"  /> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This seems simpler than the JS method, and has the advantage that there ought to be less main CPU usage - though I haven't completely investigated whether it will use the GPU automatically.

Comment: THAT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! MUCH THANKS. MUCH!!!!!!

Comment: BUT: the code adds a style to the img in the css. That style applies to all image on that page. So another image on the page is now invisible. Is there a way to  protect (or immunize) an image from that style? If I create a table like this  table {border-spacing 10px 20px} but on the same page I want just a regular table, how would I do that?

Comment: Sorry yes I was lazy. Use a class rather than the img tag.

Comment: So, pardon my ignorance: Would this work (it doesn't but not sure why):

.rotating {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: rotateimgs;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--interval) * 3);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}
 
img.rotating:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  position: relative;
}
img.rotating:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: var(--interval);
  }
img.rotating:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--interval)*2);
  }

but that doesn't work

Comment: I think I want to apply .rotating to the images which rotate and not to ones that do not. But then how do I handle the nth-child issue?

Comment: I've changed the snippet, adding a class fadeinout to each of the imgs so it's only them that pick up the fading.

Comment: YES, that did the trick perfectly. THANK YOUI THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!